# Extracting summary info from multiple files in R

Tags: r, loops, file, for-loop, extract

I'm using R to retrieve the counts of row numbers that have positive values in a certain column from multiple csv files in R. My files look like:

```
name       logFC
```

PRUPE_8G224700  9.40378466
PRUPE_1G439500  7.964239712
... 1005 genes with positive logFC...
PRUPE_6G218300  -7.950190576
PRUPE_1G341900  -7.855000528
... 2005 genes with negative logFC...

I wanted to have the counts of genes with positive logFC (i.e., 1005) and counts of genes with negative logFC (i.e., 2005) for each file.

I got warning of: "Error in append(nrow(file)) :
argument "values" is missing, with no default"

Any idea to fix this?

Thank you so much!

I used code as follows:

```
files <- list.files("/path/")
count_p <- data.frame()
count_n <- data.frame()

for (file in files){
    file <- read.csv(file, header = T)  
    count_p <- append(nrow(file$logFC>0))
    count_n <- append(nrow(file$logFC<0))
}
```

I'm expecting count_p has a list of numbers showing the counts from each file according to my criteria, and same to count_n as well.